# How to update one element of a csv with information from another csv?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a csv with rows of products like

```
SKU;price;availability;Time;Supplier;CatCode
x1;10.00;0;1-4-2019;sup1;K1
x1;10.00;0;1-4-2019;sup1;K3
x1;10.00;0;1-4-2019;sup1;K2
```

And another csv

```
CATCODE;MARGIN
K1;0.08
```

I tried the following code to update only one element of the list row wher ethe catcodes from each csv match. In this case it should only update K1, while the other values stay the same. Here is what I tried:

```
def ChangeToFinalCSV():
    SetFixMinPrices = SetFixPrices()
    CatCodes = GetCatCodes()
    for FixMinPrice in SetFixMinPrices:                         
        for cat in CatCodes:
            if cat[0] == FixMinPrice[5]:
                FixMinPrice[1] = (((float(FixMinPrice[1].replace(',','.').replace('€','')) + float(SupplierShipping)) * float(BankingComission))*(1+float(cat[1]))) * float(1.24)
                FixMinPrice[1] = "{:.2f}".format(FixMinPrice[1])
                FixMinPrice[1] = str(FixMinPrice[1]).replace('.',',') + ' €'            
                retailed.append(FixMinPrice) 

    return retailed   
retailed = ChangeToFinalCSV()
```

But this code changes all elements, not only the row with K1 as CatCode
I thought of doing it with enumerate of Python but I don't know how. How do I update only where the catcodes in both files match? I want to multiply the price by the margin with the formula `new_price=price(1+margin)`.

I try to have a csv like the initial not a pandas table

like

```
SKU;price;availability;Time;Supplier;CatCode
x1;10.80;0;1-4-2019;sup1;K1
x1;10.00;0;1-4-2019;sup1;K3
x1;10.00;0;1-4-2019;sup1;K2
```

Comment: In order to work we need to place float like df_final['price']=np.where(df_final['margin'].astype(float).isnull(),df_final['price'].astype(float),df_final['price'].astype(float)*(1+df_final['margin'].astype(float))*1.24)

Comment: @davedwards ok I just did

Comment: If you notice only the price of SKU x1 should be changed

Comment: then you want to write that new output back to a new csv file, or the same csv file?

Comment: to a new csv would be better

Comment: seems the problem may be in how you are reading in the data from the `csv` files, or in other code that you have not shown us. Please try to create a [mcve] so we can reproduce your results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without `pandas`, using only standard python and the `csv` module, here's one way to do it. `data.csv` is the "csv with rows of products", `update.csv` is the other.

```
#coding=utf-8
import csv

def GetCatCodes():
    with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
        return list(reader)

def SetFixPrices():
    with open('update.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
        return list(reader)

def ChangeToFinalCSV():
    SetFixMinPrices = SetFixPrices()
    CatCodes = GetCatCodes()
    for cc in CatCodes:
        for sfp in SetFixMinPrices:
            if cc['CatCode'] == sfp['CATCODE']:
                update_value = float(cc['price']) + float(sfp['MARGIN'])
                cc['price'] = str(update_value)
    return CatCodes

retailed = ChangeToFinalCSV()

with open('newdata.csv', 'w') as f:
    fieldnames = ['SKU', 'price', 'availability', 'Time', 'Supplier', 'CatCode']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(retailed)
```

`newdata.csv` now contains:

```
x1,10.08,0,1-4-2019,sup1,K1
x1,10.00,0,1-4-2019,sup1,K3
x1,10.00,0,1-4-2019,sup1,K2
```

Comment: It changes every price again

Comment: Then the problem exists elsewhere in your code that you have not shown us. See demo here, it only updates `K1` price: https://repl.it/@downshift/AuthenticBulkyRay If you can show us your example where it is changing *every* price, we can help fix that, but with the limited information you have shown, this does what you have asked in the question.

Comment: I went to link and copy paste the real csv files but in newdata shows the sample result

Comment: Did you push the `'Run'` button on the top of the page, to run the code and create the new output?

Comment: Yes :) I deleted it but is not created again. I type print(cc['price'] I cleared the csv from € sign and for comma put dot but all changed. About the code I have almost the same instead of dictionary lists

Comment: After you delete the file, reload the webpage, then press `Run` to run the script again, it should then output a `newdata.csv` file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191128/discussion-between-nikos-and-davedwards).

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with pandas using a [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#put you file path here instead of mine
#Just change the stuff in quotes to the path where the csvs
#you want to process are, making sure to inlclude the correct names
#csv1 should have the bigger dataset, csv2 is just the margin and catcode
csv1_filename='U:/PLAN/BCUBRICH/Python/Tests/merge_test/csv1.txt'
csv2_filename='U:/PLAN/BCUBRICH/Python/Tests/merge_test/csv2.txt'

df1=pd.read_csv(csv1_filename, sep=';') #save first csv as dataframe
df2=pd.read_csv(csv2_filename,sep=';')  #save second csv as dataframe

#merge the two so that if there is a catcode in the second file the new 
#column margin will be filled with the correct value
df_final=df1.merge(df2, left_on='CatCode',right_on='CATCODE', how='outer')

df_final['price']=np.where(df_final['MARGIN'].isnull(),df_final['price'],df_final['price']*(1+df_final['MARGIN'])*1.24)

df_final.to_csv('your_path\file_name_you_want.txt', sep=';',index=False)
```

Here is your original csv.

[image]

Here is the final output of the merged dataframes.

[image]

Comment: Yes but how I could do margin+vat+price with pandas?

Comment: I want the price to be updated lets say price = ((margin*price)+price)*1.24

Comment: It does the checking of NaN automatically and goes to next row?

Comment: Only if there is a margin , that was my next thought :)

Comment: If this is working for you and you accept the answer we can delete a bunch of these comments. I'm deleting mine already.

Comment: instead of txt I just put the file.csv correct? and how to export it to new csv?

Comment: I get TypeError ufunc multiply did not contain a loop with a signature matching types dtype ('<u32')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191119/discussion-between-nikos-and-bart-cubrich).